# Как инициализировать массив кнопок в цикле?

Tags: java, android, button, for

```
Button button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
Button button13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
Button button14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
Button button21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button21);
Button button22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button22);
Button button23 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button23);
Button button24 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button24);
Button button31 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button31);
Button button32 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button32);
Button button33 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button33);
Button button34 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button34);
Button button41 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button41);
Button button42 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button42);
Button button43 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button43);
Button button44 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button44);
button11.setOnClickListener(this);
button12.setOnClickListener(this);
button13.setOnClickListener(this);
button14.setOnClickListener(this);
button21.setOnClickListener(this);
button22.setOnClickListener(this);
button23.setOnClickListener(this);
button24.setOnClickListener(this);
button31.setOnClickListener(this);
button32.setOnClickListener(this);
button33.setOnClickListener(this);
button34.setOnClickListener(this);
button41.setOnClickListener(this);
button42.setOnClickListener(this);
button43.setOnClickListener(this);
button44.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**Нужно как-то так**

```
for (int i=1;i<5;i++){
    for (int j=1;j<5;j++){
        Button buttonij = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonij);
        buttonij.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: А вам точно это нужно? может проще в разметке указать нужный метод в `onClick`? Использование большого количества `View` на экране может приводить к сильным просадкам производительности. Рекомендуется в таких случаях использовать списки, например `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1.** Найти ID через метод `getIdentifier()`

```
for (int i=1;i<5;i++){
   for (int j=1;j<5;j++){
       String buttonID = "button" + i + j;
       int resursID= getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
       button[i][j] = (Button) findViewById(resursID);
       button[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
   }
}
```

**Вариант 2.** Перечислить все ID ресурсов в массив.

```
int[] buttons = new int[] {R.id.button11, R.id.button12, R.id.button13, ... }
```

И пройтись циклом по массиву

```
for(int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    button[i] = (Button) findViewById(buttons[i]);
    button[i].setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант я использую для объявления (Имена в xml TextView_01, TextView_02, TextView_03....)

```
public static TextView[] _name_parameter_txt = new TextView[40];

for (int i = 0; i < _count_line; i++) { 
   _name_parameter_txt[i] = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView_0 + i);
}
```

Для клика на примере Radiobutton

```
_set_click_RB(RB_weather_1, RB_weather_2, RB_weather_3, RB_weather_4, RB_weather_5, RB_weather_6, RB_weather_7, RB_weather_8);

public void _set_click_RB(RadioButton ... v) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < v.length) {
        v[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        i++;
    }
}
```